# Laravel: Integrate Stripe without laravel cashier

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, stripe-payments

I want to integrate Stripe in my application. I don't want to use laravel cashier because I am not using subscriptions etc. Also I don't want to modify my existing database. What I need to do is to checkout user's in a shopping cart and store order, order details etc in my DB. I know, I can download stripe API for PHP but is there a better way or I can also do my job with the laravel cashier? If stripe for PHP is the sollution then how can I do this in "laravel way"?

Comment: read this article http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/integrating-stripe-into-laravel-4-application/

Comment: Yea, I have seen that. Also this discussion on laracasts is also helpful for me https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/installing-package-in-laravel-5